# How to add redirect in htaccess for all urls not cotaining specific string?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, wordpress

I'm having some htaccess issues with my wordpress blog. My previous url's were something like

> article-name.html

Now I changed the structure to

> blog/article-name.html

But I'm still getting 404 for old url's I shared on various other sites. I've tried adding in htaccess a rule, also tried "redirection" plugin with no success:

[image]

and in .htaccess I tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).)*.html$ - /blog/$1.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex appears to be a problem, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).+?\.html)$ /blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Never test it there it is not reliable site. Test it locally. btw I had tested this rule before posting. Any ir redirects `anything.html` to `/blog/anything.html` Make sure this is **you very first rule**

Answer (score 0):

Change the **RewiteBase**

But your **.htaccess** is not an Original WordPress .htaccess. Why you dont use that?

Comment: I added this to the end of original .htaccess